# tf.gradients application on a function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, low-level-api

```
x = tf.Placeholder(shape=[1,31,5,1])
def func(x):
    operations...
    return output

convolutionFunction = func(x)
sess = tf.Session()
gradientConv1 = gradientConv1 + sess.run(tf.gradients(tf.square(reward-convolutionFunction), weightsConv1))
```

gradientConv1 (numpy array of shape [2,2,1,32])
weightsConv1 (tensor variable of shape [2,2,1,32])

I'm getting an error such that "Placeholder should have a dtype of float and shape of [1,31,5,1]". It seems that it is showing me that I have not given a feed_dict to the function in sess.run? Please point me out to the error.
Also is my way of differentiating with respect to each value correct.

reward is a scalar

Comment: TensorFlow differentiation is performed using autodiff, not a symbolic technique. You cannot get gradient information without first providing a 1x31x5x1 tensor of values to place in the placeholder.

Comment: So basically, do I have to provide the point at which I want to find the gradient, how can I give it here?

Comment: Correct, you can pass it by adding a parameter to `sess.run` as follows: `feed_dict={x: POINT}` where `POINT` is typically given as a Python/numpy array.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gradientConv1 = gradientConv1 + sess.run(tf.gradients(tf.square(reward-convolutionFunction), weightsConv1), feed_dict={x: <valueOfPlaceholder> })
```

where valueOfPlaceholder is the point at which we wish to evaluate the function

Thanks to Andrey Akhmetov for pointing this out!